# FBSDKShareDialog delegate not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, delegates

I use the latest Facebook SDK for iOS platform.I use FBSDKShareDialog to share image to Facebook,the code can share image to Facebook.But I want to get the share result delegate.

```
- (void)sharedImage:(UIImage *) sharedImage
 fromViewController:(UIViewController *) fromViewController {
    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo  = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
    photo.image             = sharedImage;
    photo.userGenerated     = YES;

    FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
    content.photos = @[photo];

    FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
    dialog.fromViewController = fromViewController;
    dialog.shareContent = content;
    dialog.delegate = self;
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet;
    [dialog show];
}
#pragma mark - FBSDKSharingDelegate
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results {

}
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

}
- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer {

}
```

Also I add suggest code in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    return YES;
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                   openURL:url
                                         sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                annotation:annotation];
}
```

But the FBSDKSharingDelegate method has been never called.

Comment: is the post is successfully shared?have u added `FBSDKSharingDelegate` to ur viewcontroller

Comment: @muku I have addd delegate FBSDKSharingDelegate.But not in viewcontroller subclass.

Comment: can u share the code where u have added it,and where it is used

Comment: This is my project [ThirdPartyShareDemo](https://github.com/tbago/ThirdPartyShare-EN) in github.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are setting `fromViewController` properly but that controller should be the delegate not the object.Below is code that is working and delegate is getting called

```
- (IBAction)facebookButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    //    FacebookShare *facebookShare = [[FacebookShare alloc] init];
    //    [facebookShare sharedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook_share"]
    //            fromViewController:self];
    FBSDKSharePhoto *photo  = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
    photo.image             = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook_share"];
    photo.userGenerated     = YES;

    FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
    content.photos = @[photo];

    FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
    dialog.fromViewController = self;
    dialog.delegate = self;
    dialog.shareContent = content;
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet;
    [dialog show];
}

//FBSDKSharingDelegate
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results {
    NSLog(@"completed");
}

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"fail %@",error.description);
}

- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer {
    NSLog(@"cancel");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you code work well.But I cannot understand why the Facebook api design like this.This design will make my view controller bigger and difficult to maintain .

Comment: I am a new user to stackoverflow,I will upvote you as soon as I have enough reputation.

Comment: Cancel method is not getting called

Answer (score -1):

In my case ,that 's  because my view controller has dismiss , so that's impossible to call my delegate function. So please check weather your view controller was dismissed . Hope would help .